# Is there any way to retrieve sum of grandchild field values on parent object

Tags: loop, childrelationship, object-relational-mapping

I am trying to iterate from parent to grandchild.
Is there any way to do this as I want to show the sum of grandchild field value on parent object.
please suggest me the best solution to do this other than trigger on grandchild object.
I am trying below code but it is giving an error as: "`Invalid type: Schema.childs__r`"

```
   public class CountGCRecords {
        List<parent__c> pr=new List<parent__c>();
        public CountGCRecords()
        {
        for(parent__c pc:[select ID,(Select ID from childs__r) from parent__c])
        {
            for(child__c ch:[select Id,(Select ID from grandchilds__r) from pc.child__r])
            {

            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problems in this code.

1. You are making a query in the for-loop, which is not the best practice. Learn apex best practices [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices)
2. You are using child relationship name (`pc.child__r`) in query after `FROM` clause, but it should be API name of the Object.
   The correct query will be: `select Id,(Select ID from grandchilds__r) from Child__c WHERE ID in :pc.child__r`. Now you won't get the error: `Invalid type: Schema.childs__r`
   `__r` is used to fetch relationships only.
3. You can get the Childs and Grandchild in a single query like below.

   `child__c[] childs = [SELECT id, parent__c, (SELECT ID FROM Grandchilds__r) FROM Child__c WHERE Parent__C in :pr];`
4. Even you can use aggregate queries as mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use AggregateResult to achieve the same like

```
List<AggregateResult> childValueasperParentRecord = Select AccountID, SUM(numberField__C) FROM Contact group BY AccountID
```

in the above query, Contact is child record and accountID is referring to the parent account object

You can use WHERE Clause to refine the result and for detailed documentation please use the below link

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm

Comment: thanks for your response but from above we can do it for parent child only . I want it for parent-child-grandchild .

Comment: you want to sum a number field from child and gran child or you just want to count number grandchild and chid records what is your exact scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can use roll up summary field to do this. create a roll up summary field on child to sum up values from grand child field and then create a roll up summary field on parent object to sum up newly created roll up summary fields on child object.

Comment: Hi Bilal,
Relationship is lookup not master detail.

Comment: You can use Declarative Rollup Summary Tool it is free and you can create roll ups for look up relation too from this.

Link to app: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B45gWEAR

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/07/a-declarative-rollup-summary-tool-for-force-com-lookup-relationships.html

Answer (score 0):

I can see multiple mistakes in your code.

First is you have written SOQL inside the for loop, which is not good. because as per salesforce best practices: we should not write SOQL inside the loop.

for more knowledge you can visit: https://developer.salesforce.com/index.php?title=Apex_Code_Best_Practices&oldid=26951

Second while you are writing parent query then you can use relationship field name like 'pc.child__r'. You should always use object API name like 'child__c'

so you can use this query:
Select Id, (Select ID from grandchilds__r) from child__c where Id IN:pc.child__r

I hope you find the above solution helpful.